# Как сделать бэкграунд

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять каким образом  создавать подобные бэкграунды не используя заранее заготовленное изображение.

[image: background]

Comment: Эта статя тебе поможет https://habrahabr.ru/company/raiffeisenbank/blog/346770/, если присмотреться на фон, видно деление на градиенты)

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Что-то похожее

```css
.variant1,.variant2{
  height:50vh;
  border:1px solid;
}
.variant1{
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #6ac4e6 200px,#61c0e7 250px);
}
.variant2{
  background:linear-gradient(-45deg,#6ac4e6 47%,#61c0e7 50%);
  background-size:50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="variant1"></div>
<div class="variant2"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Без изображений создать данный фон крайне сложно: создается много div-ов на заднем плане через for на js с абсолютной позицией на заднем плане. Паттерн (форма секции) создается через свойство border. 
Альтернатива: делается одна секция фона и задается фоновым изображением:

```
body{
background-image: url("1.png");
}
```

секция повторяется много раз и закрывает фон. Настройка повторения: св-во repeat в css.
Можно самим создать данный паттерн: [Сайт PatternNinja](https://patterninja.com/)

Comment: Данное решение здесь не подходит, это все через css можно сделать, т.к. "изображений" здесь фактически нет.

Comment: @DaemonHK Сделать треугольники просто, сложно заполнить ими фон (через createElement в цикле) и задать им правильную позицию.

Comment: Зачем `js`? На чистом `css` делается, посмотрите ответ выше